# Changing scala local variables scope

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka-stream

The following is a Scala code snippet of an error handler I'm making for a streaming application. It uses akka streams to consume messages ('errormsg') in a Kafka topic and write them to a table in Kudu.

```
val kafkaMessages: Source[ConsumerMessage.CommittableMessage[String, Array[Byte]], Consumer.Control] = Consumer.committableSource(
    consumerSettings,
    Subscriptions.topics(conf.getString("kafka.topics.errorRawCdr")))

  val cdrs: Source[Errors, Consumer.Control] = kafkaMessages.map(msg => {
    val bytes: Array[Byte] = msg.record.value()
    val errormsg = (bytes.map(_.toChar)).mkString
    new Errors(1235, "filename", "cdr", "cdr_type", 0, errormsg)
  })

  cdrs.to(new ErrorKuduSink(session, table)).run()
```

I'd like to re-use the variable '**errormsg**' further down, as part of a few lines that email me that message.

How do I escape '**errormsg**' (or alternatively incorporate the code snippet below), so that the variable scope is appropriate?

```
  send a new Mail (
    from = ("errorhandler@domain.com"),
    to = "myemailadres@domain.com",
    subject = "Encountered error",
    message = errormsg
  )
```

Comment: Why not sending the mail after creating the `errormsg` val?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I propose an easy fix to your problem by using a [MutableList](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~hmiller/scaladoc/library/scala/collection/mutable/MutableList.html):

```
val kafkaMessages: Source[ConsumerMessage.CommittableMessage[String, Array[Byte]], Consumer.Control] = Consumer.committableSource(
    consumerSettings,
    Subscriptions.topics(conf.getString("kafka.topics.errorRawCdr")))

    import scala.collection.mutable._
    val errorMessages: MutableList[String] = new MutableList

  val cdrs: Source[Errors, Consumer.Control] = kafkaMessages.map(msg => {
    val bytes: Array[Byte] = msg.record.value()
    val errormsg = (bytes.map(_.toChar)).mkString
    errorMessages += errormsg
    new Errors(1235, "filename", "cdr", "cdr_type", 0, errormsg)
  })

  cdrs.to(new ErrorKuduSink(session, table)).run()
```

Comment: This looks promising, but in its current form I get an error "Expression of type Errorhandler.kafkaMessages.Repr[(Errors,String)] doesn't conform to expected type (Source[Errors, Consumer.Control], String)"

Comment: Did you use the cdrs._1 property and you got this message?

Comment: I did. It marks the code under kafkaMessages.map(...), so I assume the kafkaMessages definition needs some adjusting.

Comment: As I understand you have a list of error messages that you need to send via an email. Another fix is to have a mutable list outside of the kafkaMessages.map scope so you can add these strings as you go though the messages.

Comment: Defining a mutable list first indeed does the trick. Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: send email right in your map method (will send email on every kafka message)

```
def sendEmail(errormsg: String): Unit = ???

val cdrs: Source[Errors, Consumer.Control] = 
  kafkaMessages.map { msg => 
    val bytes: Array[Byte] = msg.record.value()
    val errormsg = (bytes.map(_.toChar)).mkString
    sendEmail(errormsg) // call function that sends email
    new Errors(1235, "filename", "cdr", "cdr_type", 0, errormsg)
  }
```

Solution 2: if you want more complex usage of `errormsg` in downstream stages you need to return a tuple from your map stage:

```
val kafkaMessages: Source[ConsumerMessage.CommittableMessage[String, Array[Byte]], Consumer.Control] = 
  Consumer.committableSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics(conf.getString("kafka.topics.errorRawCdr")))

val cdrs: Source[Errors, Consumer.Control] = 
  kafkaMessages.map { msg => 
    val bytes: Array[Byte] = msg.record.value()
    val errormsg = (bytes.map(_.toChar)).mkString
    (new Errors(1235, "filename", "cdr", "cdr_type", 0, errormsg), errormsg) // we are returning a tuple so type of downstream elements will be (Errors, String)
  }.map { case i@(errors, errormsg) => 
    sendEmail(errormsg)
    i
  }.map { tuple =>
    ...
  }.map(_._1) // as we dont need a tuple any more we can get original element and continue processing of it


cdrs.to(new ErrorKuduSink(session, table)).run()
```

Solution 3: if you want even more complex processing (for example to batch multiple errormsg in one email) you may want to create a [RunnableGraph](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.4/scala/stream/stream-graphs.html)

```
val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._
  val in = Consumer.committableSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics(conf.getString("kafka.topics.errorRawCdr")))
    .map { msg => 
      val bytes: Array[Byte] = msg.record.value()
      val errormsg = (bytes.map(_.toChar)).mkString
      (new Errors(1235, "filename", "cdr", "cdr_type", 0, errormsg), errormsg)
    }
  val kuduout = new ErrorKuduSink(session, table)
  val emailout = Sink.foreach[Seq[String]] { errormsgs =>
    sendEmail(errormsgs)
  }
  val f1 = Flow[(Errors, String)]
    .map(_._1) // take errors

  val f2 = Flow[(Errors, String)]
    .map(_._2) // take errormsgs
    .groupedWithin(100, 1.hour)

  val bcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](2))

  in ~> bcast
  bcast ~> f1 ~> kuduout
  bcast ~> f2 ~> emailout 
  ClosedShape
})
```